# Acces list element in flutter? Geocoding

Tags: flutter, geocode

I am trying to get the latittude from the list :

> [      Latitude: 28.6139391,
> Longitude: 77.2090212,
> Timestamp: 2022-06-12 11:34:06.992Z ]

which is generated by this code below:

```
  Future fetchAlbum() async{
List locations= await locationFromAddress("New Delhi, India");
print(`locations`);
 }
```

i want to get lattitiude so i am trying :

```
print(locations[0])
```

but it getting me same output but without square brackets :

> Latitude: 28.6139391,
> Longitude: 77.2090212,
> Timestamp: 2022-06-12 11:34:06.992Z

Answer (score 0):

Looking at documentation: https://pub.dev/documentation/geocoding/latest/geocoding/locationFromAddress.html

It seems like the method returns `List<Location>` which you can access it easily.

Please change your code to:

```
Future fetchAlbum() async {
  final locations = await locationFromAddress("New Delhi, India");
  print(`locations`);
  if (locations.isNotEmpty) {
     final location = locations.first; // or locations[0]
     print(location.latitude)
     print(location.longitude)
  }
}
```